# 40-96 VAC to DC conversion

Tags: integrated-circuit, ac-dc

I am trying to build a simple voltage meter. One that displays the AC voltage onto a small LED display run from an Arduino Micro. I have the nuts and bolts down but I'd like to be able to power the Arduino, transformer module, and display from the AC source I'm measuring. My question is, all the AC-DC ICs I've found have a minimum AC voltage of around 80 VAC. My source will be, at worst case, half of that.

Am I overcomplicating this by adding an IC to do the conversion?

Comment: Rectify it and look for a DC/DC capable of approximately 50-140 V DC input instead. IC is the way to go unless you current is very low.

Comment: You may use one of these circuits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier